# Unregistering a COM dll using regsvr32

Tags: asp-classic, regsvr32, dllregistration

I've registered a COM dll using the regsvr32 command and I forgot the exact location of the assembly from where I did it. Now I'm facing trouble to unregister the dll. How I can unregister it? I tried using the /u switch from other locations of the assembly but that's not working.. the asp application is still using the assembly successfully.

Comment: As a simple way to do this, you can locate your DLL's under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID` in the registry. Search for `ProgID` or DLL's name. The path will be there in the under one of it's sub-keys (`InprocServer32`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for getting path: http://support.softartisans.com/kbview_1294.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt with admin privilege and type:

```
regsvr32 -u dll name
```